# Circular-referencing cell changes in Excel VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

In the image below, you can see that I have three cells. What I want to have happen is that if I update the value in either D3 or D4, then D4 or D3 updates respectively. I have code below which attempts to do this. The issue I'm seeing though, is that if I update D3, the macro executes, updating D4, which registers as a change, causing the macro to execute and updating D3, causing the macro to execute ... ad nauseam. How can I break out of this?

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Column = 4 And Target.Cells(1, 1).Row = 3 Then
        Cells(4, 4).Value = Cells(2, 4).Value * Cells(3, 4).Value
    ElseIf Target.Cells(1, 1).Column = 4 And Target.Cells(1, 1).Row = 4 Then
        Cells(3, 4).Value = Cells(4, 4).Value / Cells(2, 4).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start, then `Application.EnableEvents = True` when you're done.

Comment: @Comintern Perfect thank you! If you supply a full answer I'll accept. The nature of this problem made it somewhat hard to google.

Comment: Nah, pretty sure it's already on SO somewhere.  Just too lazy to find it.  ;-)